# Running multiple versions of Firefox

Tags: css, osx-mountain-lion

I've been reading this:
http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/797010#answer-193690

But it looks like it only applies to running multiple versions of Firefox when it's Firefox 4.

I need to run Firefox but it seems like a lot of my clients are still running versions of Firefox 3 (is this an operating system issue? Doesn't Firefox auto-update?) so I need to run 3 plus the latest version to troubleshoot some css issues...

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Mountain Lion, sorry I forgot to add that.

Comment: FF can auto-update, but the users can turn automatic updating off if they want. And yes, older versions of the OS can't run the very latest Firefoxes; for instance FF 15.0 requires MacOS 10.5 or higher. By the way, I'm pretty sure the way to run multiple FFs (in the link you provided) works for other versions as well.

Comment: Also note that Firefox will auto-update when you launch it so if you want to turn it off you should disable your internet connection the first time you launch it so you can get into the settings before it tries. Had this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for testing is to get the [Portable Apps Edition of Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) for the various versions.  This avoids profile and addon conflicts.

They only list a few of the older versions on the website, for rest you have to goto the [Firefox section of their SourceForge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox,%20Portable%20Ed./).

In the same folder as the FirefoxPortable.exe, create a file called FirefoxPortable.ini and add the lines:

```
[FirefoxPortable]
DisableSplashScreen=true
AllowMultipleInstances=true
```

To run more than one edition at the same time and remove the splash screen delay.

Comment: Hey, I've added the file you said with the contents above. I am still getting an error saying: another instance of firefox is already running portable.... I think I don't get how to remove the splash screen delay part. Could you elaborate? I am running windows 10

Comment: @sanjihan The above only turns off the 'instance' check on the portable version.  If you run the portable first, then another firefox, it will error, as the non-portable is still checking.  If you run just the portable version, do you see a splash screen? If so your .ini is wrong or in the wrong location.

Comment: Ahh, I manually typed in .ini extension, but the file remained to be a text file.    Once I got the extension right it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be also interested in online services like [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) or [Adobe BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html#), which provides web page view for many different OS-browser-version combinations...